# Simulating simple boolean logic

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement the simple boolean logic in ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.4a (Verilog).

[image]

i.e. `x = A*B+C' y = C'`

Here's the code I'm using in verilog

```
module smpl_circuit(A,B,C,x,y);
  input A,B,C;
  output x,y;
  wire e;
  and g1(e,A,B);
  not g2(y,C);
  or g3(x,e,y);
endmodule
```

I'm getting the below output on simulating the above logic. I'm unable to understand why I'm getting straight lines.

[image]

Is there anyway so that I can input Boolean values (`0`/`1`) to the waves and get Boolean output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need a testbench. A testbench is another Verilog module that provides stimulus (inputs) to your design (`simpl_circuit` in your case) and can even check the outputs for you. Much of the Verilog process is not only writing your designs but also the test mechanisms to show the system works.

Now, there are ways using the console in Modelsim to force various lines high and low. In sim prompt, you can use `force smpl_circuit/A 1` to hold `A` at logic one (I am not used to Modelsim, so I cant give you exact syntax/instructions). However, a bunch of `force` commands really isnt a substitute for a good testbench, so learn to write them now while you have relatively simple designs!

For more on testbenches:
https://embeddedmicro.com/tutorials/mojo/writing-test-benches

For on force:
http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/courseware/cse2306/2006/Pracs/force.pdf